# Unable to route user to dashboard successfully

Tags: php, jquery

I have some logic in the login_Submit.php file which checks a user's role type and then directs them to the correct dashboard (i.e. admin, supervisor or student).

The redirecting is fine and works well, however instead of loading the whole page my code loads the dashboard page within the login page so it looks like this:

[image: Login Page with dashboard]

when it should redirect and fully load the page like this:

[image: Student dashboard]

I'm assuming it has something to do with the jQuery but I'm not entirely sure what the problem is.

The jQuery code:

```
function loginCall() {
  var data = $('#loginForm').serialize();
  $.post('LoginSubmit.php', data, function(response){

   $("#loginForm").html(response);

  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
  });
}
```

The redirection based on role type:

```
if($user_record_id == false)
        {
                $message = "<p class='text-danger'>Login Failed</p>";
        }
        /*** if we do have a result, all is well ***/
        else
        {
                /*** set the session user_id variable ***/
                $_SESSION['user_record_id'] = $user_record_id;
                // echo $user_record_id;
                switch( $user_role_code){ //not sure whether to use role_type_code or role_title because i want the name rather than the code

               case 1:
                    echo "Wrong Username or Password";

                case 2:
                    header("location:AdminDashboard.php");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    header("location:SupervisorDashboard.php");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    header("location:StudentDashboard.php");
                    break;
                }
            }
```

UPDATE

The jQuery code:

```
 function loginCall() {
      var data = $('#loginForm').serialize();
      $.post('LoginSubmit.php', data, function(response){

       $("#loginForm").html(response);
    window.location.replace(response);

      }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
      });
    }
```

The redirection based on role type:

```
if($user_record_id == false)
        {
                $message = "<p class='text-danger'>Login Failed</p>";
        }
        /*** if we do have a result, all is well ***/
        else
        {
                /*** set the session user_id variable ***/
                $_SESSION['user_record_id'] = $user_record_id;
                // echo $user_record_id;
                switch( $user_role_code){ //not sure whether to use role_type_code or role_title because i want the name rather than the code

               case 1:
                    echo "Wrong Username or Password";

                case 2:
                    echo "AdminDashboard.php";
                    break;

                case 3:
                    echo "SupervisorDashboard.php";
                    break;

                case 4:
                    echo "StudentDashboard.php";
                    break;
                }
            }
```

still no luck :(

Comment: You cannot redirect your whole page from an AJAX request. With `$('#loginForm').html(response)` you put the result of the AJAX call (which will give you the entire redirected page) inside your form. If all you need is a redirect, omit the JQuery :)

Comment: Try debugging your AJAX call using something like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client), and you'll get a better understanding.

Comment: thanks for the help. its very hard debugging in safari so I'm always on the lookout for tools like this. will give it a go! it is possible to serialise the data and send it to the php file without messing up the JQuery?

Comment: If you want to keep using `ajax request`, so you need to make redirection in client side with javascript. You can get the user role code for example as a returned response from `LoginSubmit.php` page and redirect with javascript to the right page.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you comment out  `//header("location:SupervisorDashboard.php");` you can see it loads login page.

You have load the content inside `loginForm`

```
$("#loginForm").html(response);
```

What happen here is you load the login and inside that it happens the redirection.

I think, you don't need the Jquery here. You can remove that code and just do it from the serverside.

Comment: Hi thank you for the response. I initially use JQuery to submit the data to the php page. even after removing that line i still get the same issues for some reason :/ so confused

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect your page using an AJAX call directly.

Instead of using `header("location: SomePage.php")` as the result of your call, why not `echo "SomePage.php";`

Then, with the returned page, you can redirect using Javascript if you must:

```
window.location.replace(response);
```

**Edit**: Actually, you can do this without JQuery and AJAX, which is a much simpler approach. Set up your form like so:

```
<form action="LoginForm.php">
...
</form>
```

And on the `LoginForm.php`, make sure to redirect to the right page using the `header()`:

```
header('Location: SomePage.php');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @sgtdck i've just tried to use the echo and then added the additional line to the jQuery how its getting an object not found fault. any ideas how i can overcome this? i have updated the original question with the changes. thanks

Comment: @user90210 try this: `echo json_encode("AdminDashboard.php")`. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your help @sgtdck i've just tried and I'm getting an object not found error :/ don't know why this doesn't work. Is there a simpler way without using the jQuery?

Comment: Sure, you can do without JQuery and AJAX altogether. Submit the login form with `<form action="LoginSubmit.php">` and do the `header('Location: ....');`. That way you end up at the right page directly.

Comment: Yeah just done that and it works fine. was getting complicated with the ajax and jQuery. Thank you so much for your help though! :D

Comment: No worries @user90210 I have updated the answer to include the right approach. Could you accept it as the 'accepted answer' if you found it helpful? Thanks!